# Acumatica API Create SalesOrder with multi DocumentDetails row

Tags: php, erp, acumatica

When I create a SalesOrder with multi DocumentDetails in PHP, here is my code

```
$SO301000Submit->commands = array
        (
            $acumatica->prepareValue("SO", $SO301000GetSchema->OrderSummary->OrderType),
            $SO301000GetSchema->Actions->Insert,
            $acumatica->prepareValue("ACTIVESTAF", $SO301000GetSchema->OrderSummary->Customer),

            $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->ServiceCommands->NewRow,
            $acumatica->prepareValue("HQ", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->Branch),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("AALEGO500", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->InventoryID),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("WHOLESALE", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->Warehouse, true),

            $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->ServiceCommands->NewRow,
            $acumatica->prepareValue("VA", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->Branch),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("AAPOWERAID", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->InventoryID),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("RETAIL", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->Warehouse, true),


            $SO301000GetSchema->Actions->Save,
            $SO301000GetSchema->OrderSummary->OrderNbr
        );
        $result = $acumatica->client->SO301000Submit($SO301000Submit);
```

It will return the error

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at PX.Api.SyImportContext.ParseCommand(SyCommand cmd)
>      at PX.Api.SyExportContext.ParseCommand(SYMappingField field)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at PX.Api.SyExportContext..ctor(SYMapping mapping, IEnumerable`1 fields, String[] providerFields, Dictionary`2 viewFilters, Boolean breakOnError, Int32 start, Int32 count, Dictionary`2 selectorViews, String rowFilterField)
>      at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, Command[] commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
>      at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
>      at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
>      at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

But if I reduce code with single DocumentDetails as below:

```
$SO301000Submit->commands = array
        (
            $acumatica->prepareValue("SO", $SO301000GetSchema->OrderSummary->OrderType),
            $SO301000GetSchema->Actions->Insert,
            $acumatica->prepareValue("ACTIVESTAF", $SO301000GetSchema->OrderSummary->Customer),

            $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->ServiceCommands->NewRow,
            $acumatica->prepareValue("HQ", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->Branch),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("AALEGO500", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->InventoryID),
            $acumatica->prepareValue("WHOLESALE", $SO301000GetSchema->DocumentDetails->Warehouse, true),

            $SO301000GetSchema->Actions->Save,
            $SO301000GetSchema->OrderSummary->OrderNbr
        );
        $result = $acumatica->client->SO301000Submit($SO301000Submit);
```

Then, Everything is OK, a SalesOrder is created.

Here is function prepareValue:

```
public function prepareValue($value, $command, $needcommit = false, $ignore = false)
{
    $value_command = new ObjectDocument\Value();
    $value_command->Value = $value;
    $value_command->LinkedCommand = $command;
    if($needcommit) $value_command->Commit = true;

    $soapvar = new \SoapVar($value_command, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "Value", "http://www.acumatica.com/generic/");
    return $soapvar;
}
```

I don't know why? Please help me to explain this case.

Comment: We tried the same set of commands here with a C# console application, and it worked. I suspect that the SOAP message that is sent by PHP is slightly different, which is causing our server to crash.

Comment: Also, can you take a look at the SOAP message that is generated and maybe paste it here? It will allow us to see what's missing and the difference with our message.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just release from other project. Mr @DChhapgar make a perfect answer for my trouble. Thank  you so much.

Comment: Glad to know that @DChhapgar helped you! Please accept his answer so that this question is mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Gabriel mentioned, SOAP message that is sent by `PHP` is slightly different.
Issue is that the `XML` created for the request from PHP introduces the id in the `XML` and then wherever it finds the same node it just passes the id as the reference.

Example (below SOAP message is captured using Fiddler):-

[image]

To overcome this, create two different items with the same structure. You may utilize `clone`

Create new function `PrepareValueExt` as below and use it for lines.

```
public function PrepareValueExt($value, $command, $needcommit=false, $ignore=false)
{
    $value_command = new Value();
    $value_command->Value = $value;
    $value_command->LinkedCommand = clone $command;
    //$value_command->IgnoreError = $ignore;
    if($needcommit) $value_command->Commit = true;

    return($value_command);
}
```

And Change code for NewRow as well:

```
array_push($command, clone $schema->DocumentDetails->ServiceCommands->NewRow);
```

Comment: GREAT, Thank you so much. I just come back from other project, sorry you for late reply. I test your code and it run right. Thank you again.

Comment: @Indulgence, I am glad it is resolved. Please accept it as an answer :)